# Passing arguments in jquery ajax resulting in undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to jQuery. I'm creating a cascading dropdown using jquery ajax. So based on the changed value of first dropdown, the second script fetches values from database from second dropdown.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#builder_group").change(function () {
        var selected_builder = $(this).val();
        alert(selected_builder);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'getGroupzCode.php',
            data: 'selected_builder',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                // Call this function on success                
                console.log(data);
                var yourArray = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(yourArray);
                $.each(yourArray, function (index, yourArray) {
                    $('#builder_group1').append($('<option/>', {
                        value: yourArray.id,
                        text: yourArray.name,
                    }));
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                displayDialogBox('Error', err.toString());
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Problem is when I alert the selected value from first dropdown it works i.e             alert(selected_builder) works , but when I try to pass it to the script it is showing as undefined in PHP script. How can I solve this.

Comment: Still I get  Undefined index: selected_builder

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass it as a string.

```
data: selected_builder,
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a string as your `data`. Try passin `selected_builder` without the surrounding `'`, like this:

```
 data: selected_builder,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data: 'selected_builder'+data
```

It should be key value pair

Comment: It already was a key:value pair. Please explain what appending `+data` does here.

Comment: ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: what you want to pass getGroupzCode.php file

Answer (score 1):

Pass the variable name instead of string.

```
data: selected_builder,
```

Answer (score 1):

When passing as a json string (for sending using jQuery ajax), let native javascript stuff do it for you. Pass your data as a correct JSON string to be interpreted by your target.

```
data  : JSON.stringify({ selected_builder : selected_builder})
```

This will allow your receiving method to get the data as a parameter named selected_builder.